# Store Credentials for SecureString use in .config

Tags: c#

I have a library that I'm using, but didn't write that takes authentication credentials as SecureString values. I would like to store those values in an application configuration file as plain text with the type of SecureString. I haven't found anywhere showing how to do this. Is it possible, or is the only to this is to build a SecureString object from the configuration file values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely possible...at least if you're using ASP.NET.  Jon Galloway wrote up a good post on it here:  http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx

Also, here's a Microsoft Walkthrough on [Creating & Exporting an RSA Key Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w117ede%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which might be of some help.

Lastly, another [Microsoft guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998283.aspx#paght000006_webfarmscenarios) (although a bit different) - talks about using the machine key.

These guides will allow you to create a `<secureAppSettings>` section that contains encrypted values are accessed in code the same way as non-secure app settings.

Comment: The Jon Galloway post is great because it reminds us that even after using the config file protections in the MS links, you are left with a sensitive string in unprotected memory.  Unless MS changes the ConfigurationManager class to also be able to fetch settings as SecureStrings, there is a risk for buffer overflows exposing in-memory sensitive strings via HeartBleed-like exploits.  But to really be thorough, you probably need a hardware TPM involved behind the scenes for the decryption, in order to eliminate the possibility of memory leakage.

Comment: I appreciate that this was posted a while ago, but what this answer amounts to is a set of hyperlinks, two of which are now obsolete and unlikely to be available for long... -1